# Booting error with mm.c:376: out of memory

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

My machine (Dell PowerEdge r940[4sockets and RAID]) has been working well for a while without any crush before.
But someday, it stops to boot with the error as below

```
../../grub-core/kern/mm.c:376: out of memory.

Press any key to continue...
```

But the weird thing is that only complied kernels incurs such a problem.

The default kernel that came with Ubuntu does not incur this error and works well.

I tried to install another ubuntu (20.04), and it has the same error (only with compiled kernels)

I have recovered grub, but that doesn't work.

I installed fedora too, and it works well without any problems even with compiled kernels.

Do you have any ideas?

P.S. After typing sth on the error page, the following kernel panic occurs.

```
.
.
.
Kernel Offset: 0xb000000 from 0xffffffff81000000 (relocation range: 0xfffffff80000000-0xffffffffbfffffff)

---[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)]---
```

Comment: If you experiencing problems with the kernel compiled by yourself most probably you missing some kernel configurations. I recommend you to use the working kernel's .config file, you can grab it by `gzip -d /proc/config.gz > .config`, put it in your kernel sources tree, and run `make oldconfig`, after that you can compile your kernel further.

Comment: I've tried it and failed... I just switched my OS to Fedora, and it works fine...